# How to change this code to find all matches

Tags: vb.net

I need to perform a substring match on the ID. For example, search for all the IDs that begin with "AB" and return all matches. ID format is AB1234.

```
    Dim CPosition, HashPostion As Integer
    Dim StudentID, Fileline, IdPart As String
    Dim SPostion As Char
    Dim found As Boolean = False

    FileOpen(1, "StudendRecord.txt", OpenMode.Input)

    Console.Write("Enter ID to find the email: ")
    StudentID = Console.ReadLine()

    Do
        CPosition = 1
        Fileline = LineInput(1)

        Do
            SPostion = Mid(Fileline, CPosition, 1)
            CPosition = CPosition + 1
        Loop Until SPostion = "#"

        HashPostion = Len(Fileline) - (CPosition - 1)
        CPosition = 1
        Do
            SPostion = Mid(Fileline, CPosition, 1)
            IdPart = IdPart + SPostion

            If StudentID = IdPart Then
                Console.WriteLine("the email: " & Right(Fileline, HashPostion))
                found = True
            End If
            CPosition = CPosition + 1
        Loop Until SPostion = "#"
    Loop Until EOF(1)

    If found = False Then
        Console.WriteLine("ID not found.")
    End If
    FileClose(1)
```

Comment: AB1234#David@yahoo.com
AB4321#John@gmail.com
CD1234#snow@yahoo.com
CD4321#Al@yahoo.com

Comment: Why are you looking for '#'?

Comment: The File "StudentRecord.txt" is like this:

Comment: Is each address on a separate line?

Comment: AB1234#David@yahoo.com 
AB4321#John@gmail.com 
CD1234#snow@yahoo.com 
CD4321#Al@yahoo.com 
(all are four different lines)

Comment: Then you should just be able to use If `FileLine.StartsWith("AB")...` WHERE "AB" would be replaced with a string variable containing user input.

Comment: Also, you might take a look a the IO.StreamReader() for reading the file line by line.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using regex?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this code add Imports System.IO to the top of the file. This namespace has a File class. File.ReadLines returns and array of the lines in a text file.

I created a simple class to hold the data in the file.
Then a list of the class's type.
I then split each line on the # character getting a 2 element array. The first element will contain the ID and the second element contains the email.
Create a new student and pass the data to the constructor. Then add the new student to the list.

To search the list I used Linq. Linq returns an IEnumerable(Of T) T in this case is StudentRecord.

To search the list I used Linq. I used .ToArray on the resulting IEnumerable because we only need the first element.

```
Public Class StudentRecord
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Sub New(id As String, email As String)
        Me.ID = id
        Me.Email = email
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Private StudentRecords As New List(Of StudentRecord)
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim Records = File.ReadLines("StudentRecord.txt")
        For Each line In Records
            Dim SplitLine = line.Split("#"c)
            Dim stu As New StudentRecord(SplitLine(0), SplitLine(1))
            StudentRecords.Add(stu)
        Next
        Console.Write("Enter ID to find the email: ")
        Dim StudentID = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim students = From stu In StudentRecords
                       Where stu.ID.StartsWith(StudentID)
                       Select stu
        If students.Count > 0 Then
            For Each stu In students
                Console.WriteLine($"Student {stu.ID} email is {stu.Email}")
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("ID not found.")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```